# How to fix SimpleExoPlayer.stop() on a null object reference?

Tags: android, exoplayer

> I am unable to stop the Video Playback when the viewpager is scrolled.

> This is my MainActivity's Viewpager scrollListener code :

```
       viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
                simpleExoPlayer1.stop();    //error is here
                Log.e("onPageScrolled", "onPageScrolled");

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                Log.e("onPageSelected", "onPageSelected");

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
                Log.e("onPageScrolStateChang", "onPageScrollStateChanged");
            }
        });

        myAdapter = new VideoSliderAdapter(getApplicationContext(), videoPaths,
                MainActivity2.this, this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);    

    }

    @Override
    public void clicktoupdate(ImageView playPause, int position,
                              PlayerView playerView,
                              SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer1) {
        // get data
        Toast.makeText(this, "Playing..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videoPaths.get(position));
        playPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        playerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        simpleExoPlayer1 = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSeekBackIncrementMs(5000)
                .setSeekForwardIncrementMs(5000)
                .build();
        playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer1);
        playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        simpleExoPlayer1.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                if (playbackState == Player.STATE_BUFFERING) {
//                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {
//                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri);
        simpleExoPlayer1.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
        simpleExoPlayer1.prepare();
        simpleExoPlayer1.play();
    }
```

> This is my Adapter's Viewholder code :

```
   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    PlayerView playerView;
    ImageView thumbnailImage;
    ImageView playPauseBtn;
    ImageView bt_fullscreen, bt_lockscreen;
    SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    LinearLayout sec_mid, sec_bottom;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
        super(view);
        playerView = view.findViewById(R.id.statusSliderVideo);
        thumbnailImage = view.findViewById(R.id.statusSliderThumbnailImage);
        playPauseBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.playPauseBtn);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        bt_fullscreen = view.findViewById(R.id.bt_fullscreen);
        bt_lockscreen = view.findViewById(R.id.exo_lock);
        sec_mid = view.findViewById(R.id.sec_controlvid1);
        sec_bottom = view.findViewById(R.id.sec_controlvid2);
        playPauseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    onitemclicklisteners.clicktoupdate(playPauseBtn, position, playerView, simpleExoPlayer);
                }
            }
        });
    }


}

public interface Onitemclicklisteners {
    void clicktoupdate(ImageView playPause, int position, PlayerView playerView, SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer);

}
```

> As soon as the App starts, this is the Error I am getting :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer.stop()' on a null object reference
```

> I think I have to make the `simpleExoPlayer1 global` in MainActivity ,  please help me fix this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried null checking?
Something like this:

```
if (simpleExoPlayer1 != null) {
  simpleExoPlayer1.stop();
}
```

That'll fix the crash.
But maybe a problem is elsewhere in you code; have you initialized `simpleExoPlayer1` before registering `OnPageChangeCallback`?

Comment: I am unable to create a Global Instance of simpleExoPlayer1 , can you please help

Comment: @Zibran, what do you mean? I mean why you're unable: are you seeing some error? Can you tell the exact problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `simpleExoPlayer1` object is being instantiated in your `clicktoupdate()` interface override. The `clicktoupdate()` function only gets called **when the view holder is clicked**. So when you first open the app, the `onPageScrolled()` must be getting called for some reason and it is trying to stop the `simpleExoPlayer1`. However, the `simpleExoPlayer1` has not been instantiated, since the user has not clicked the view holder! So that is why it is crashing - the `simpleExoPlayer1` object has not been instantiated and therefore is null.

There are a few things that you could do to solve this, but I would have thought that the `simpleExoPlayer1` could be instantiated once inside the activity's `onCreate()` method, so moving it there should fix your issue.

Try moving the following snippet to inside your onCreate(), before the view pager listeners are called.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    simpleExoPlayer1 = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setSeekBackIncrementMs(5000)
        .setSeekForwardIncrementMs(5000)
        .build();
    
    viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(...);
    ...
}
```

Final tip: use camel case to define your methods & variables For example, `clicktoupdate()` should be `clickToUpdate()`. It makes it way more readable :)

Comment: I am unable to create a Global Instance of simpleExoPlayer1 , can you please have a look

Comment: What do you mean you can't create a class level instance of SimpleExoPlayer? Try declaring `SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer1;` above the onCreate() method, that should work.